# Free or affordable MacOSX Style Icons

Tags: user-interface, macos, icons

I would need about two dozens of MacOSX style Toolbar Buttons for mostly typical stuff.
I don't need exclusive rights on the icons, so i would like to purchase an icon set.

There are hunderts of icons sets available for free and purchase for Windows Style. But i haven't seen any for MacOSX now. Thats strange.

I know about a few icon sites (sorry don't have my bookmark list on this computer) which have a few but they are not really considered production stuff. They are more public designer portfolios with irrelevant fun stuff like monster or christmas icons. Or application icons for other Applications - they are really carefully with not putting out something that hurts there business.

Individual designed icons are extremely expensive - in the range of 100-400 US$ per icon - which is definitely out of my financial capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "PInvoke" icon set (http://pinvoke.com/). It is in the Mac style and it is dual-licensed: Creative Commons CC-BY or commercial.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly familiar with Mac styling differences, but wouldn't [Tango icons](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Icon_Library) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try [iconfinder](http://www.iconfinder.net/search/?q=iconset%3Ahumano2)? "Mac" doesn't yield a hell of a lot of results, but you you peek around you can find some nice shiney icons that should fit well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the standard icon set included with the OS X Developer Tools (you'll find them in Interface Builder's palette), Mac developers often spend more on icon development than in on other platforms. Mac users expect (and appreciate) more exactly relevant icons so it's worth spending the money for ones designed specifically for your app.

Comment: This is a worthwhile and informative post. I know entire houses of people dedicated to making NOTHING but icons. I wish I could remember their names right now. They're extremely good at what they do, though.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to check out some of the icons sets on http://iconpot.com.

Answer (score 0):

http://stockicons.com/

http://iconkits.com/